# Query to find the 2nd highest temperature for each month?

Tags: sql

I am struggling with this query and cant seem to get the solution for it. I have to calculate the 2nd highest temperature in each id for each month. the table has 3 columns. The table:

[image]

here is what i have done:

```
select weather_station_id wst, month(dates) months, max(max_temp) maxtemp2
from stations
where max_temp < (select max(max_temp) from stations)
group by weather_station_id, month(dates);
```

With my code(below) it checks the value against every iteration and gives 2nd highest in comparison to the previous value not the overall. can someone please show how to get the 2nd highest for every id in each month?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask] and the guidlines in the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: I am using sql server management studio version 15

Answer (score 0):

Use window function `row_number`.

> Group the rows by `weather_station_id, month (dates)` and then sort them
> desc by `max_temp` and retrieve row 2.

```
row_number() over(partition by weather_station_id,month(dates) order by max_temp desc) as seq
```

---

```
select wst,months,max_temp
from
  (select weather_station_id wst,
       month(dates) months,
       max_temp,
       row_number() over(partition by weather_station_id,month(dates) order by max_temp desc) as seq
  from stations) t
where seq = 2
```